# How to solve this unfamiliar initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I haven't learned how to solve this problem because the differential equation is non-linear. What's my approach?

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sin(tx),\space x(0)=\pi \space\text{for}\space  0\le x\le 10$$

Comment: _Who_ set you the problem? Is it supposed to be solved numerically?

Comment: My teacher. I assume it's supposed to be solved numerically and then we are to check our work using MATLAB. I might be misinterpreting something however.

Comment: Indeed there is no closed-form solution. There's this thing called Euler's method which you might want to try. Go look it up.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=tx$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{u}{t}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{u}{t^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-\dfrac{u}{t^2}=\sin u$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{t^2\sin u+u}{t^2}$

$(t^2\sin u+u)\dfrac{dt}{du}=t$

Let $v=t^2$ ,

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=2t\dfrac{dt}{du}$

$\therefore\dfrac{(t^2\sin u+u)}{2t}\dfrac{dv}{du}=t$

$(t^2\sin u+u)\dfrac{dv}{du}=2t^2$

$(v\sin u+u)\dfrac{dv}{du}=2v$

Let $w=v+u\csc u$ ,

Then $v=w-u\csc u$

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{dw}{du}+(u\cot u-1)\csc u$

$\therefore(\sin u)w\left(\dfrac{dw}{du}+(u\cot u-1)\csc u\right)=2(w-u\csc u)$

$(\sin u)w\dfrac{dw}{du}+(u\cot u-1)w=2w-2u\csc u$

$(\sin u)w\dfrac{dw}{du}=(3-u\cot u)w-2u\csc u$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}=(3\csc u-u\csc u\cot u)w-2u\csc^2u$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $w=\dfrac{1}{z}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{du}=-\dfrac{1}{z^2}\dfrac{dz}{du}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{z^3}\dfrac{dz}{du}=\dfrac{3\csc u-u\csc u\cot u}{z}-2u\csc^2u$

$\dfrac{dz}{du}=2z^3u\csc^2u+(u\csc u\cot u-3)z^2$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2